# Get variable from function

Tags: php, oop, function

in simple oop , we get result from function like this

```
<?php 
class A{
function geta(){
.....
$a=..;
return $someresult;}}
?>
```

to get result from function geta(), we just create new instance

```
$new=new A();
echo $new->geta();
```

my ask, how to access variable $a?

Comment: You are well advised [to read the PHP manual on classes, objects, and properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) If `$a` is needed outside the function, then you'll need to make it a class property with the appropriate public visibility, or private visibility and a getter method.

Comment: `class A { public $a; public function geta() { $this->a = 'newvalue'; } }`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access that $a like that, you should use the `$this` command:

```
<?php 
class A{
private $a = "Hello world";
function geta(){
  return $this->a;}}
?>
```

If you call a function `geta()` then it should return `a`. That's a best practice that is almost a must, since other people uses similar naming functions to return these values.